# How to get a resource with it's ID according to a string variable in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-resources

I have my code currently like this:

```
riddle_no += 1;

String riddleString = "riddle_" + riddle_no;

String riddle = getResources().getString(R.string.riddleString);
```

I want to replace 'riddleString' in getString() with the string variable. So far I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SagarHatekar I have riddles in an xml file under values.  I want to get, for example, riddle_1 according to the variable riddleString. If I manually insert riddle_1 it works. But I want it to change as I change the variable.